# Computational complexity of matrix-vector product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, computational-complexity

I was reading through [this lecture](http://theory.stanford.edu/~trevisan/expander-online/lecture03.pdf) when I found the following claim:[image]

I was wondering how the number of operations is $O(k(n + m))$, and not $O(kn^2)$ for vectors $\mathbf{x}$ of size $n \times 1$ and $\mathbf{M}$ of size $n \times n$. I looked through papers that talk about complexity optimizations for matrix-vector multiplication, but have never seen papers that show linear complexity in terms of number of nonzero elements of the matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you store the matrix. If you store only the non-zero elements (as is often done for [sparse matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix)), then you only need one multiplication and one addition per non-zero element: You loop over the non-zero elements, multiply them with the corresponding element of the input vector and add the result to the corresponding element of the output vector. (You also need to initialize $n$ sums to zero; that's where the contribution $kn$ comes from.)